# Insertion of an array into a new php file

Tags: php

I am trying to insert an array into a php file . However I am able to insert the array into a php file but the format is not as desired . We have 2 files

File1.php

```
<?php
include_once("../dc/dcCommonLib.php");
include_once("../dc/persistence/UserData.php");
require_once("../../lib/include/connect.inc.php");

$_SESSION["survey"] = "BestBuyAug2012";
$idLink = dbconnect($_SESSION["survey"]);
$surveyWidget = rendererSurveyLoadHandler();
setDataToSession("surveywidget",$surveyWidget);
$userData = &UserData::getInstance();
$userData->setSurvey($surveyWidget);
saveFkidsToOidToFkidMappingArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping);

// prepare demo array
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Demographic"]["Q"],$demo,"b");

// prepare item array
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Default"]["Q"],$item,"i");
prepareItemArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Default"]["M"],$item,"i");

// prepare comment array
prepareCommentArray($userData->OidToFkidMapping["Comment"]["C"],$comment);

if(!function_exists('file_put_contents')) {
    function file_put_contents($filename, $data,$type, $file_append = false) {
      $fp = fopen($filename, (!$file_append ? 'w+' : 'a+'));
        if(!$fp) {
          trigger_error('file_put_contents cannot write in file.', E_USER_ERROR);
          return;
        }
    if($type){

    $count = count($data);
    $i = 1;
    //loop through your type array and append comma , to each except last
    foreach($data as $key=>$val) {

     //if we are before last key, append comma    
     if($i < $count)
          $data[$key] .= ',';

       $i++;
    }

    //run same preg_replace as before
    $data2 = preg_replace('/[\[\]]/','"',print_r($data,TRUE));

    //write to file 
    fputs($fp, "$" . $type . " = " . print_r($data2,TRUE));     

 }      else {
        fputs($fp, print_r($data, TRUE));
      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
}
print("Strart writting ...................");
file_put_contents("staticSurveyDataFileTest.php", "<?php\n","",true);
file_put_contents("staticSurveyDataFileTest.php", $item,"itemFkids",true);
file_put_contents("staticSurveyDataFileTest.php", $demo,"demoFkids",true);
file_put_contents("staticSurveyDataFileTest.php", $comment,"commentFkids",true);
file_put_contents("staticSurveyDataFileTest.php", "?>","",true);
print("written ...");

function prepareItemArray($userDataArray, &$item, $itemStr) {
    if(is_array($userDataArray)) {
        foreach($userDataArray as $questId=>$respGrp) {
            $selectionGrp=array_unique($respGrp);
            if(count($selectionGrp)==1) {
                $respGrpId=key($respGrp);
                $respId = key($respGrp[$respGrpId]);
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$itemStr.$respGrp[$respGrpId][$respId];           
            }else {
                foreach ($respGrp as $respGrpId=>$resp) {
                    $respGrp[$respGrpId]=$itemStr.$resp;
                }
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$respGrp;
            }
        }
    }   
}

function prepareCommentArray($userDataArray, &$item) {
    if(is_array($userDataArray)) {
        foreach($userDataArray as $questId=>$respGrp) {
            $selectionGrp=array_unique($respGrp);
            if(count($selectionGrp)==1) {
                $respGrpId=key($respGrp);               
                $item[$questId."_".key($respGrp)]=$respGrp[$respGrpId]["fk_id"];            
            }
        }
    }   
}

?>
```

The array from this file is inserted into another file by name staticSurveyDataFileTest.php

staticSurveyDataFileTest.php

```
<?php
$itemFkids = Array
(
    "203_19" => i27,//double quotes missing  
    "207_22" => i28,//double quotes missing 
    "357_22" => i99,//double quotes missing 
    "370_70" => i104,//double quotes missing
    "377_72" => i105,//double quotes missing 
    "140_8" => i1,//double quotes missing 
    "141_8" => i2,//double quotes missing 
    "142_8" => i3,//double quotes missing 
    "143_8" => i4,//double quotes missing 
    "144_8" => i5,//double quotes missing 
    "145_8" => i6,//double quotes missing 
    "151_8" => i7,//double quotes missing 
    "152_8" => i8,//double quotes missing 
    "158_8" => i9,//double quotes missing 
    "164_8" => i10,//double quotes missing 
    "165_8" => i11,//double quotes missing 
    "166_8" => i12,//double quotes missing 
    "167_8" => i13,//double quotes missing 
    "168_8" => i14,//double quotes missing 
    "169_8" => i15,//double quotes missing 
    "175_8" => i16,//double quotes missing 
    "176_8" => i17,//double quotes missing 
    "182_8" => i18,//double quotes missing 
    "183_8" => i19,//double quotes missing 
    "184_8" => i20,//double quotes missing 
    "190_8" => i21,//double quotes missing 
    "196_8" => i22,//double quotes missing 
    "197_8" => i23,//double quotes missing 
    "198_8" => i24,//double quotes missing 
    "199_8" => i25,//double quotes missing 
    "200_8" => i26,//double quotes missing 
    "214_8" => i29,//double quotes missing 
    "215_8" => i30,//double quotes missing 
    "216_8" => i31,//double quotes missing 
    "222_8" => i32,//double quotes missing 
    "223_8" => i33,//double quotes missing 
    "224_8" => i34,
    "225_8" => i35,
    "226_8" => i36,
    "227_8" => i37,
    "233_8" => i38,
    "234_8" => i39,
    "235_8" => i40,
    "236_8" => i41,
    "237_8" => i42,
    "243_8" => i43,
    "244_8" => i44,
    "245_8" => i45,
    "251_8" => i46,
    "252_8" => i47,
    "253_8" => i48,
    "254_8" => i49,
    "255_8" => i50,
    "256_8" => i51,
    "257_8" => i52,
    "263_8" => i53,
    "264_8" => i54,
    "265_8" => i55,
    "266_8" => i56,
    "267_8" => i57,
    "268_8" => i58,
    "269_8" => i59,
    "270_8" => i60,
    "271_8" => i61,
    "272_8" => i62,
    "278_8" => i63,
    "279_8" => i64,
    "280_8" => i65,
    "281_8" => i66,
    "282_8" => i67,
    "283_8" => i68,
    "289_8" => i69,
    "290_8" => i70,
    "296_8" => i71,
    "297_8" => i72,
    "298_8" => i73,
    "299_8" => i74,
    "300_8" => i75,
    "301_8" => i76,
    "307_8" => i77,
    "308_8" => i78,
    "309_8" => i79,
    "310_8" => i80,
    "311_8" => i81,
    "312_8" => i82,
    "313_8" => i83,
    "314_8" => i84,
    "315_8" => i85,
    "316_8" => i86,
    "317_8" => i87,
    "318_8" => i88,
    "324_26" => i89,
    "328_37" => i90,
    "332_48" => i91,
    "338_59" => i92,
    "344_59" => i93,
    "345_59" => i94,
    "351_8" => i95,
    "352_8" => i96,
    "353_8" => i97,
    "354_8" => i98,
    "364_8" => i100,
    "365_8" => i101,
    "366_8" => i102,
    "367_8" => i103 
)//comma missing
$demoFkids = Array
(
    "129_2" => b1//double quotes missing 
)//comma missing
$commentFkids = Array
(
    "373_375" => 1,//double quotes missing 
    "380_382" => 2//double quotes missing 
)//comma missing
?>
```

We need to insert a file something like this

Desired Output

```
<?php
    $itemFkids = Array
    (
        "203_19" => "i27",//notices the double quotes here
        "207_22" => "i28",
        "357_22" => "i99",
        .
        .
        .

        .
        .
.

    ),//notice a comma here
    $demoFkids = Array
    (
        "129_2" => "b1"//notices the double quotes here
    ),//notice a comma here
    $commentFkids = Array
    (
        "373_375" => "1",
        "380_382" => "2"//notices the double quotes here
    ),//notice a comma here
    ?>
```

I did try to search in google and other php websites but did not find much about this . 
So I would really appreciate IF YOU CAN EDIT MY CODE and make this work .
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Given the strict and limited format of your data, you could easily do this by doing a string replace on closing braces.

Comment: @BillyMoon Hello billy . Could you please show me the line of code

Comment: How are you going to retrieve the data from your file? It's not valid php in either of your examples, since each of the declared arrays should be terminated with a semi-colon `;`;

Comment: @Crisp This is exactly what I am asking . How can I do it ? I need a semicolon at the end of each array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a database, in my opinion.
At any rate I think a `foreach` would work if a better solution is not found.

Example:

```
$second_array = array();

foreach($first_array as $key => $value){
    $second_array[$key]='&quot;'.$value.'&quot;';
}
```

This is assuming the quotes are for html display.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please try to write answers in normal formatting, not all monospaced code. A little more care with forming proper sentences would be appreciated as well. Thanks.

Comment: 10-4------------ i deleted mine... your turn.

Comment: @jat still not sure why the quotes are necessary, please provide additional info

Comment: That is just for display purpose my friend .Where should I add it in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [serialisation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). It's a different approach from what you're doing, but a lot cleaner.
Simply, it's a way to take a PHP object, turn it into a string (which can be saved, read, etc.) and deserialisation will convert it back to the way it was.

Comment: I will surely read upon it but I need to make my code to work asap . So could you edit my same code and make it work ?