# insert array of new item in any position in another array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add new item to array? For example into middle of an array ?Should we use `array splice` or an `array merge` ?
 Could you explain me the difference between  both function ?

Say I have

```
$a1=array("a"=>"Horse","b"=>"Dog","c"=>"Cow",);
$a2=array("d"=>"Cat");
```

Now I need to add $a2 in 2 position .

Which one should I use ?

Comment: show us the particular array, what you want to add, where, and under what conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice), except that won't keep your keys.

```
$a1 = array("a"=>"Horse", "b"=>"Dog", "c"=>"Cow");
$a2 = array("d"=>"Cat");

array_splice($a1, 2, 0, $a2);

// $a1 is now: array("a"=>"Horse", "b"=>"Dog", 0=>"Cat", "c"=>"Cow");
```

If you want `Cat` to have a key of `d`, you can use a mix of [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice) and the [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (`+`):

```
$a1 = array_slice($a1, 0, 2) + $a2 + array_slice($a1, 2);

// $a1 is now: array("a"=>"Horse", "b"=>"Dog", "d"=>"Cat", "c"=>"Cow");
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516816/insertion-of-an-array-into-a-new-php-file question as well ?With the kind of reputation you have that would be a childs play for you . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to add array at any position. ..array_splice can also be used. .
example: [array_splice](http://www.ferolen.com/blog/insert-into-add-element-to-array-at-specific-position-php/)

Comment: `array_push` adds to the end of the array.

Comment: I need that to be added in the middle ?

Comment: Array_splice is the correct approach . Thanks